# <asp:hyperlink> after opening target in new window - new window cannot be closed

Tags: asp.net

I've got a page with an  control - the link is to a gif file.  Right clicking on the link (in IE7) and selecting "open target in new window" correctly displays the image.  However I can't then close the new IE window.

**MORE INFO:** Works OK in Firefox 3

What might I be doing wrong ?

TIA

Tom

Comment: How exactelly are you trying to close the new window? You you click on the red X and nothing happens? Or are you trying to close it from JS code?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really something you can **do wrong** to prevent a window from being closed on the client.

My guess is this is a problem with the system installation.

Test this again using another browser on the same computer, and then on another computer.